# Macintosh IIsi Hard disk pinout

Tags: hardware

A simple one if you know the answer: how many pins does the [SCSI interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI) on the Mac IIsi have.

I thought I could just pull drives from my SE/30 collection but it sounds like that's not the case. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mac SE/30 and IIsi use the same SCSI interfaces, and you should be able to swap drives freely between them (though a Mac OS system that'll boot one won't necessarily work with the other).  More specifically, both have:

- A 25-pin DB-25 external connector. This is nonstandard, but it's the same interface Apple used starting with the Mac Plus, and IIRC ending with the beige PowerMac G3s.
- An internal 50-pin header connector (data) and 4-pin Molex power connector. This *is* standard; see the "Internal Industry Standard 50-pin SCSI F/W" connectors in [this IBM doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/scsi-connector-photos-specifications-and-options-servers-and-intellistation). In fact, pretty much all 8-bit ("narrow") SCSI drives from that era use this same internal interface (though the standard external interface is a 50-pin Centronics connector, with the same pinout as the internal header version).

Answer (score 1):

The IIsi has a DB-25 SCSI port.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/sp199

Unless you really want to reuse existing drives for reasons (and there are several I can imagine) an emulator is also a good option.

- https://tom.scsi.blue/product/bluescsi-db25/
- https://github.com/erichelgeson/BlueSCSI/wiki/Supported-Systems

Note the IIsi doesn’t provide termination power, so that might be why you are thinking the [pin out is sus](https://github.com/erichelgeson/BlueSCSI/wiki/Supported-Systems#macintosh-iisi).

> The IIsi does not provide TERM POWER. It must be powered via the Berg connector or USB on the BluePill.
>
> From the IIsi service manual:
>
> > "The 85C80 [SCSI controller] does not provide the internal SCSI disk drive with termination power; the drive provides the termination power.”